# Using express-pino-logger and pino-pretty together

Tags: node.js, express

I'm have existing code that uses [express-pino-logger](https://github.com/pinojs/express-pino-logger). This words great with our ELK stack setup, but is pretty unfortunate (logs minified JSON) when running locally.

I'd like to use [pino-pretty](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty) to make local use not a pain.

There is an alternative in [pino-pretty-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-pretty-express) that solves the problem, but uses its own pretty formatter. I'd like to use the standard packages from pinojs if I could.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// with just pino-pretty installed, pino works out of the box
const pino = require('pino')
const logger = pino({
  prettyPrint: true
})

logger.info('hi') // prints pretty
```

And:

```
// adding this option to express-pino-logger, doesn't work
const pino = require('express-pino-logger')
const logger = pino({
  prettyPrint: true
})

logger.info('hi') // does NOT print pretty
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved my own problem I guess.

The key lies in the very last example on the [express-pino-logger](https://github.com/pinojs/express-pino-logger) page:

```
'use strict'

const pino = require('pino')()
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger')({
  logger: pino
})
```

Here's my solution:

```
// use pino-pretty and express-pino-logger together
const basicPino = require('pino')
const basicPinoLogger = basicPino({ prettyPrint: true })
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger')({
  logger: basicPinoLogger
})

const logger = expressPino.logger

logger.info('hi') // prints pretty
```

Comment: Yes, I had this answer solved before I asked the question. I also spent longer than I'm willing to admit beating on it with a hammer trying to get it to work. I'm posting here for posterity.

Comment: should you module.exports both of them? how does your logger file look like in production if you dont mind sharing

Comment: Like this (sorry about the formatting, brevity): ```
import basicPino from 'pino';
import pino from 'express-pino-logger';

let pretty = false;
if (process.env.PRETTY_PRINT && process.env.PRETTY_PRINT === 'true') {
  pretty = {
    colorize: true,
    translateTime: true
  };
};

const basicPinoLogger = basicPino({
  prettyPrint: pretty
});

// Create express middleware logger with (optionally pretty) basic pino logger
export const LogMiddleware = pino({
  logger: basicPinoLogger,
  level: log_level
});

export const Log = LogMiddleware.logger;```

Answer (score 2):

```
const pino = require('pino');
const expressPino = require('express-pino-logger');
const logger = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info', prettyPrint: true });
const expressLogger = expressPino({ logger });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context/explanation to it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the express pino logger is explicitly being used to log unique request ids. There is an alternative approach using the http-context and node-uuid (although I am unsure about the benchmark results)

You can create a unique uuid before the call of each request like this

```
const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
....
  app.use(httpContext.middleware);
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
            httpContext.set('reqId', uuid.v4());
            next();
        });
```

.. you can obtain the requestId anywhere from the httpContext. No need of relying on the req object to be passed
Example usage in a custom implementation of PinoLogger service

```
public infoLogService (fileName): pino.Logger {
        return pino({
            level: 'info',
            name: this.appService.getApp_name(),    

            messageKey: 'feedback-Logs',
            base: {pid: process.pid, hostname: os.hostname,
                timestamp: this.getTimeStamp(),
                appName: this.appService.getApp_name(),
                fileName: fileName,
                request_id: isNullOrUndefined(httpContext.get('reqId')) ? 'Not an actual request ' : httpContext.get('reqId')
            },
            enabled: true,
            useLevelLabels: true,
        });
    }
```

For every http calls, we get a UUID. for other type of loggings like logger invocation before the app starts to find if the connection to database happened successfully, there will be no uuid and hence passed a default message